# Cannot get Python3 to recognize installed modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I have scoured across StackOverflow and Google and have not been able to find a solution. I'm currently running the macOS Big Sur beta and I have Python 3.8.5 installed via homebrew. I have pip3 installed numpy and scrapy but anytime I try to import them I get:

```
AJs-MacBook-Pro:~ AJ$ cd PycharmProjects/Python/Projects/Web\ Scrape/
AJs-MacBook-Pro:Web Scrape AJ$ python3 scraper.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

As far as I know here is my only Python3 install:

```
AJs-MacBook-Pro:~ AJ$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Here is pip3:

```
AJs-MacBook-Pro:~ AJ$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

My pip3 list:

```
AJs-MacBook-Pro:~ AJ$ pip3 list
Package          Version
---------------- -------
attrs            20.2.0
Automat          20.2.0
cffi             1.14.2
constantly       15.1.0
cryptography     3.1
cssselect        1.1.0
hyperlink        20.0.1
idna             2.10
incremental      17.5.0
itemadapter      0.1.0
itemloaders      1.0.3
jmespath         0.10.0
lxml             4.5.2
numpy            1.19.1
parsel           1.6.0
pip              20.1.1
Protego          0.1.16
pyasn1           0.4.8
pyasn1-modules   0.2.8
pycparser        2.20
PyDispatcher     2.0.5
PyHamcrest       2.0.2
pyOpenSSL        19.1.0
queuelib         1.5.0
Scrapy           2.3.0
service-identity 18.1.0
setuptools       50.3.0
six              1.15.0
Twisted          20.3.0
w3lib            1.22.0
wheel            0.34.2
zope.interface   5.1.0
```

I have nothing added in my bash profile. I am not sure where I am going wrong, any advice would be more than appreciated!

Edit: So I watched a tutorial on Youtube by Corey Schafer on how to setup a venv and that seems to fix my issue. Any modules downloaded into the venv are importable by Python with no issues. Thanks for the suggestions everyone!

Comment: what is your call to pip3? You have the output from the .py run in the first example, but how are you actually calling the installation?

Comment: I'm sorry I am still really new to all of this, I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: so are you running 'pip3 numpy' for example, to actually install the package?

Comment: If you just run `python3` are you able to import numpy?

Comment: @Michael no when I do that it tells me:
AJs-MacBook-Pro:~ AJ$ python3 import numpy
/usr/local/bin/python3: can't open file 'import': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @DavidWarren when I install modules I use "pip3 install numpy" for example.

Comment: In general I recommend using venv to setup python environments that are sandboxed, which also happens to help with concerns over whether you've got your environment properly configured because each venv comes with its own activation script. So you could have a "Web_Scrape" virtual environment with its own python, pip, etc that you activate. Have a look here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: @Aeonofgods and when you do that, are you getting confirmation that the installation was successful?

Comment: Your pip3 may be installing packages to a location that's not being checked by your python3. Check the sys.path variable from inside python3, that will show you all of the directories that python looks in when searching for modules on an import request

Comment: @Michael I did start looking into that, I think I might have to start doing that going forward

Comment: @DavidWarren yes so far I have pip3 installed numpy and scrapy this way and both gave me successful confirmations

Comment: In that case Michael's feedback re: the location of the installations is likely the culprit

Comment: check if you use the same Python - `pip3 -V` and `python3 -V` or use `python3 -m pip install numpy`

Comment: @Michael how can I find the sys.path variable?

Comment: @furas This is what the first two gave me:
AJs-MacBook-Pro:~ AJ$ pip3 -V
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
AJs-MacBook-Pro:~ AJ$ python3 -V
Python 3.8.5

Comment: From within the python3 interpreter you can `import sys` and then `print(sys.path)`. Or as a one-liner from a command prompt:`python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

Comment: Here is the output:
AJs-MacBook-Pro:~ AJ$ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages']

Comment: It seems like I have no idea where pip3 is installing these modules. I did "python3 -m pip3 install numpy" and it says: /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8: No module named pip3

Comment: Looks like python3 is mostly checking a subfolder named `Cellar` for modules, and pip3 seems to be installing modules somewhere else entirely. I think there's something funky with however you installed Python3. Try creating a venv somewhere else and start over

Comment: Yeah for whatever reason pip3 is installing each module in a different place. Scrapy went to: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin
Pycodestyle went to: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Scrapy went to: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin
I'll have to try venv and hopefully it'll alleviate my issues

Comment: You need `python3 -m pip` and not `python3 -m pip3`, there is no `pip3` module. Do not trust any of the `pip`, `pip3`, etc. scripts. Only trust the module `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip ...` -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @sinoroc well in the article in mentions using venv and pipx as a better idea than downloading to your global interpreter so I'm going to give that a shot

Comment: That advice still stands, no matter what, even for virtual environments. I don't see how _pipx_ would help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried virtual environment?
https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Comment: I have not tried using them yet no, but it seems like something I'm going to need to

Answer (score -2):

Like other's have commented I recommend use a virtual env

```
$ python3 -m venv ~/web_scrape
$ source ~/web_scrape/bin/activate
```

[python 3 venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

For troubleshooting:

find where `numpy` is installed

```
pip3 show numpy
```

Look for the `Location:`  line

[python 3 module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Comment: Seems like venv is the way to go so I'll try that before messing with $PYTHONPATH. Thanks!

Comment: PYTHONPATH is almost never the right thing to do, this is a good way to break your packages

Comment: Honestly this could be the reason why I ran into issues about a month ago. I was having this same issue trying to import BeautifulSoup and a lot of answers had to do with PYTHONPATH changes in the bash profile. I have since deleted all the changes from there

Answer (score -5):

Go the my computer
-open c drive
-open users
-open your pc named file

- open app data
  -open program
  -open python
  -open scripts
  Then open cmd
  Code: pip install [module name]